# Ability to Suppress Logs?

Tags: parse-platform

Has there been any update on the ability to suppress logs, especially when dealing with entries like "Ran cloud function..." ? We'd like to provide some Cloud Functions with sensitive information and I'd like them not showing up in the logs. It also adds a lot of noise given the short history of viewable logs available.